# Finite Volume Implementation

Tags: finite-volume, mesh-generation, numpy

I am trying to implement a simple finite volume method solver. I had a class on FVM a while back, but am still aware of the principal concepts. But implementing the FVM for non-cartesian or 1D meshes is not straightforward to me.

E.g. I have a mesh representing my control volumes. I compute the cell centroids to be used as my DOF later on. How would I compute the connectivity between cell centroids? I can compute this by searching for cells that share a cell surface, but this is very naive and hence computationally very inefficient. Further, I just don't see sophisticated softwares doing so.

I am looking for anything that might help me understand some of the tricks involved in implementing a FVM solver efficiently! Things that are not directly involved with the underlying mathematical/numerical schemes, but rather the set-up.

Comment: You probably want to look at literature on grid generation and setting up data structures for FVM. I know that in OpenFOAM, for instance, they set up a graph data structure that contains the connectivity relationships of cell centers and cell faces. Iterating over adjacency lists then gives the desired adjacent cells (or faces), and I presume that normals to cell faces are stored along with the cell faces.

Answer (score 4):

I have 1D finite-volume code written in python for a *cell-centred* mesh,

[image: Cell centred mesh]

First generate a sequence which is the location of the *faces*, $
\{ x_{j-1/2} \}$. For example, for uniform spacing over the domain [0,1] this is a simple as,

```
a = 0
b = 1
J = 50 
faces = numpy.linspace(a, b, J}
```

After you have the faces the rest is easy because the faces uniquely determine the cell centres,

$$
x_j = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_{j-1/2} + x_{j+1/2} \right)
$$

and the cell volumes (only a *true* volume in 3D but we stick with the wording),

$$
h_j = x_{j+1/2} - x_{j-1/2}.
$$

For connivence you can define the centroid spacing, this is useful when interpolating values to/from centres/faces. Following [Hundsorfer's approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540034404),

$$
h_{-} = x_j - x_{j-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left( h_{j-1} + h_j \right) \\
h_{+} = x_{j+1} - x_j = \frac{1}{2}\left( h_{j} + h_{j+1} \right) 
$$

The following project on github might be useful, https://github.com/danieljfarrell/FVM to see how this can be implemented in practice. I use a `Mesh` and `CellVariable` objects ([inspired by Fipy](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/)). You can instantiate the mesh and the query it for centroid position, mesh volume etc. The `CellVariable` class using the mesh to do transparent linear interpolation of solution variable.

Here is the mesh class and an example of how to use it. It might be a useful basis for your implementation,

```
class Mesh(object):
    """A 1D cell centered mesh defined by faces for the finite volume method."""

    def __init__(self, faces):
        super(Mesh, self).__init__()

        # Check for duplicated points
        if len(faces) != len(set(faces)):
            raise ValueError("The faces array contains duplicated positions. No cell can have zero volume so please update with unique face positions.")
        self.faces = np.array(faces)
        self.cells = 0.5 * (self.faces[0:-1] + self.faces[1:])
        self.J = len(self.cells)
        self.cell_widths = (self.faces[1:] - self.faces[0:-1])

    def h(self, i):
        """Returns the width of the cell at the specified index."""
        return self.cell_widths[i]

    def hm(self, i):
        """Distance between centroids in the backwards direction."""
        if not check_index_within_bounds(i,1,self.J-1):
            raise ValueError("hm index runs out of bounds")
        return (self.cells[i] - self.cells[i-1])

    def hp(self, i):
        """Distance between centroids in the forward direction."""
        if not check_index_within_bounds(i,0,self.J-2):
            raise ValueError("hp index runs out of bounds")
        return (self.cells[i+1] - self.cells[i])

import numpy
faces = numpy.linspace(0,1,6)
mesh = Mesh(faces)
mesh.cells # i.e. cell centres
# array([ 0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0.7,  0.9])
mesh.cell_widths # i.e. cell volumes
# array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])
```